# Import webpack bundle

Tags: webpack

I am bundling this with webpack:

```
function blarg() {
  return 'warg';
}

const stuff = {
  things: 'whatnot'
}

const paraphernalia = 'junk';

module.exports = {
  blarg,
  stuff,
  paraphernalia,
}
```

When I create the bundle, I want to be able to import an object like so:

```
import obj from './bundle.js';
```

The object should look like this:

```
{
  blarg,
  stuff,
  paraphernalia,
}
```

Instead, the output is `undefined`.

I want to do it this way because the bundle is going to be an external library and I don't want that library to be responsible for attaching things to `window`.

How do I import the object from the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to output your bundle as a library.

You can update your Webpack config to include `library` and `libraryTarget` in the `output` section:

```
output: {
  // ...
  library: 'myLibraryName',
  libraryTarget: 'umd'
}
```

Full details in the docs:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/